# Analysis of recursive algorithms for max, ruler and tower of hanoi

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have following prorams from robert sedwick in algorithms in C++

```
Item max(Item a[], int l, int r){
    if (l == r) return a[l];
    int m = (l+r)/2; 
    Item u = max(a, l, m);
    Item v = max(a, m+1, r);
    if (u > v) 
        return u; 
    else 
        return v;
}
```

following is program for tower of hanoi

```
void hanoi(int N, int d)
  {
    if (N == 0) return;
    hanoi(N-1, -d);
    shift(N, d);    
    hanoi(N-1, -d);
  }
```

Following is program for ruler

```
void rule(int l, int r, int h)
  { int m = (l+r)/2;
    if (h > 0)
      { 
        rule(l, m, h-1);
        mark(m, h);
        rule(m, r, h-1);
      }
  }
```

All three above problems solve problem of size 2 to power of n by dividing it into two problems of size 2 to power of n-1.

I understand for ruler and max, but how for towerof hanoi in above statement?

While analyzing above progarams, author is mentioned that for finding maximum, we have linear time solution in the size of the input; for drawing ruler and for solving towers we have linear time solution in size of the output.

What does author mean by linear time solution in size of output above?

Comment: 'Linear time solution in size of output' just means the n in O(n) is the number of items in the output rather than the input. In this case, the number of marks which need to be drawn to get a ruler of the desired size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tower of honoi your recursive algorithm is (H(1) = 1):

> H(n) = 2 H(n-1) + 1 = 2^2H(n-2) + 2 + 1 .... = 2^(n-1) H(1) + 2^(n-2)
>   + ... + 1 =   2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) + ... + 1 = 2^n - 1.

But also the solution for towers of honoi should print 2^n - 1 moves, which is equal to running time of your algorithm, so the size of your output and the running time of your algorithms relation is linear, in fact

> lim <sub>n->∞</sub>   output / runtime = constant.

This means the running time of algorithm has a linear relation with output (but as you can see its relation with input is exponential).

Also in finding maximum again you could use such a `lim` to say it has a linear relation with input.